Awesome notification in Flutter Exception
Added Awesome notification in Flutter,its used for Android notification and only iOS local notification but when tapping on iOS Push notification its throwing a Exception.
E/Swift: E/Sw31m[AWESOME NOTIFICATIONS] The action content doesn't contain any awesome information (AwesomeExceptionReceiver:54)E/Sw0m

same problem here. any solutions ?
